# ReactTable data not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm new to React and ReactTables. I can't seem to get my data to render in my table. The table itself renders and has the correct number of rows given my dataset (adding more rows in the JSON adds more rows in the table), but nothing actually populates in the headers or in the cells themselves. I've also verified that the JSON appears to parse correctly by printing the sample_roster.players to the console. I have no custom CSS being applied to this table. Everything is default from the react-table.css being imported.

Here is sample_roster.json:

```
{
  "players":
          [
            {"name": "Bill Freehan", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "51"},
            {"name": "Bobby France", "team": "Montreal Oilers", "points": "13"},
            {"name": "Dwayne Johnson", "team": "Wrestlemania", "points": "25"},
            {"name": "Mario Lemeaux", "team": "Hockey Guy", "points": "89"},
            {"name": "Dancing Queen", "team": "ABBA", "points": "53"},
            {"name": "Eric The Red", "team": "Unicorns", "points": "43"},
            {"name": "Yasmeen Bleeth", "team": "Baywatch", "points": "151"},
            {"name": "Bill Lambeer", "team": "Detroit Pistons", "points": "8"},
            {"name": "Bill Pullman", "team": "Independence Day", "points": "111"},
            {"name": "Tony The Tiger", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "41"},
            {"name": "Johnny Cage", "team": "Mortal Kombat", "points": "33"},
            {"name": "Ricky Gervais", "team": "The Offices", "points": "2001"},
            {"name": "Chester Cheetah", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "21"},
            {"name": "Drake", "team": "Rap Guy", "points": "64"},
            {"name": "Lovely Rita", "team": "Beatles Song", "points": "11"},
            {"name": "Pinocchio", "team": "Fairy Tails", "points": "22"},
            {"name": "Pamela Anderson", "team": "Baywatch", "points": "31"},
            {"name": "Yellow Submarine", "team": "Beatles Song", "points": "221"},
            {"name": "Red Honda", "team": "Cool Cars", "points": "213"},
            {"name": "Mickey Lolich", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "121"}
          ]
}
```

Here is the class where I'm trying to do the rendering:

```
class TextRoster extends Component {
    render() {
        const playerList = sample_roster.players;
        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'Name',
                accessor: 'name'
            },
            {
                Header: 'Team',
                accessor: 'team'
            },
            {
                Header: 'Points',
                accessor: 'points'
            }
        ];
        return (
            <ReactTable
                data={playerList}
                columns={columns}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your code. Maybe there is a problem in getting the data.
I've used your data and columns and tried generating the issue, but it works without a hitch.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    const sample_rooster = {
      "players":
        [
          { "name": "Bill Freehan", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "51" },
          { "name": "Bobby France", "team": "Montreal Oilers", "points": "13" },
          { "name": "Dwayne Johnson", "team": "Wrestlemania", "points": "25" },
          { "name": "Mario Lemeaux", "team": "Hockey Guy", "points": "89" },
          { "name": "Dancing Queen", "team": "ABBA", "points": "53" },
          { "name": "Eric The Red", "team": "Unicorns", "points": "43" },
          { "name": "Yasmeen Bleeth", "team": "Baywatch", "points": "151" },
          { "name": "Bill Lambeer", "team": "Detroit Pistons", "points": "8" },
          { "name": "Bill Pullman", "team": "Independence Day", "points": "111" },
          { "name": "Tony The Tiger", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "41" },
          { "name": "Johnny Cage", "team": "Mortal Kombat", "points": "33" },
          { "name": "Ricky Gervais", "team": "The Offices", "points": "2001" },
          { "name": "Chester Cheetah", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "21" },
          { "name": "Drake", "team": "Rap Guy", "points": "64" },
          { "name": "Lovely Rita", "team": "Beatles Song", "points": "11" },
          { "name": "Pinocchio", "team": "Fairy Tails", "points": "22" },
          { "name": "Pamela Anderson", "team": "Baywatch", "points": "31" },
          { "name": "Yellow Submarine", "team": "Beatles Song", "points": "221" },
          { "name": "Red Honda", "team": "Cool Cars", "points": "213" },
          { "name": "Mickey Lolich", "team": "Detroit Tigers", "points": "121" }
        ]
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={sample_rooster.players}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: 'Name',
              accessor: 'name'
            },
            {
              Header: 'Team',
              accessor: 'team'
            },
            {
              Header: 'Points',
              accessor: 'points'
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: You can put your data on  your state too.

For more information try to follow the examples provided in the official website
 https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table